# How to track suspicious login activity in magento 2 admin panel

Tags: magento2, logging

How i can get notifications when unauthenticated user try to login in admin panel. How i can check history of failed login with IP details?

Answer (score 0):

In Magento 2 there is a setting how much time users are allowed to authenticated login.
[image]

No any IP History log, but you can log by an observer.
You can use some extensions to use this feature in community version and this is easily customizable

https://marketplace.magento.com/mageaurigait-adminlogger.html